# Wordpress redirecting to htdocs folder in xampp

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I had setup wordpress on `/blog` directory. Everything was perfect. Today I tried to tweak 2-3 things as it was not coming up on server. I came to know about `siteurl` and `home` to be defined. But after a little while its not working now anymore. I rolled back all changes (there were only 3 changes), but still issue is not getting solved. 
So while I configured wordpress it was running on `http://localhost:5000/blog`. For this reason, `options` table is also having this

```
1   siteurl http://localhost:5000/blog  yes
2   home    http://localhost:5000/blog  yes
3   blogname    Stockarea   yes
4   blogdescription Just another WordPress site yes
```

But now when I am running it back on same url that is `http://localhost:5000/blog` it redirects me to `http://localhost/blog` and gives `error 404 - Object not found!`. I have rolled back everything to its initial state and still it is like this.

I even tried to add this in wp_config.php

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://localhost:5000' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost:5000' )
```

But no luck at all. Tried restarting xampp server still no luck. Why is wordpress redirecting me to htdocs folder

Comment: change `urls` in `wp-options` in db and reset `permalinks` from `permalinks settings` in admin panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open **wp-config.php** file in the WordPress folder, and set following parameter.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost:5000/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost:5000/blog');
```

Please check your **.htaccess** file, hope the below code solve your issue :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: where do we have to have this .htaccess file. in /blog directory right?

Comment: Yes correct in blog directory. But, sometimes if its not showing up in your system, make sure you have selected the visibility ON for hidden files and folders. As the default nature of .htaccess file is hidden for being crucial file of a site.

Comment: yeah i know that but do .htaccess file work for localhost

Comment: Yes, it work in cases of directory location, redirects and permalinks

Answer (score 0):

Open **wp-config.php** file in the **WordPress folder**, and set site

```
url(define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost:5000/Stockarea/index.php');
```

folder name